# ASP.NET MVC view markup orientation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, single-page-application

I'm coming to grips with Microsoft's MVC SPA template. I've just done a tute on knockout, which seemed straightforward, and now I would like to know whether these tags, found at the beginning and end of views, are informational or functional.

```
<!-- ko with: register -->
    ...        
<!-- /ko -->
```

In this sample, the view is called `_Register.cshtml` and the AccountController does seem to have a method Register that takes a RegisterBindingModel, but there is also a file `register.viewmodel.js` the code in which looks a *lot* like the view models from the KO tute I just did.

Can someone explain to me how this works? I understand the MVC *pattern* but I'm still a little hazy on how SPA on MVC hangs together.

Are those tags perhaps some sort of RAZOR directive?

Comment: Those are comments... plain HTML comments...

Comment: Please define "KO."  Please also take care when selecting tags; you created one that already existed, and used others in odd ways.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Comment: @Romias they are actually functional Knockout bindings.

Comment: @BenFoster... hehe, yes, I just saw the knowout documentation...

Comment: Define KO? "I've just done a tute on knockout" ... "KO tute I just did". Notwithstanding the fact that I *did* define KO, there is a vanishing chance of help from anyone who needs it explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are functional and useful in cases where you do not have a container element.

From the docs:

> The  and  comments act as start/end markers,
>   defining a “virtual element” that contains the markup inside. Knockout
>   understands this virtual element syntax and binds as if you had a real
>   container element.

[More info](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html)

Comment: Thanks, Ben, for actually answering the question instead of complaining that the paperwork wasn't ISO compliant. You're a dying breed. The link to the documentation is gold. Is it just me or is knockout incredibly similar to XAML in the way you go about data binding?

Comment: Yes the attribute based binding is certainly similar to XAML.